# Assuming that passives need verbal morphology, which languages commonly said to have a passive do not actually count?

Tags: terminology, morphology, list-of-languages, passive

Among others, I recently read the passive definition by Martin Haspelmath (from *THE GRAMMATICIZATION OF PASSIVE MORPHOLOGY*, 1990), which states (page 26/27 of the book, the second/third page of the article):

> It is well known, of course,  that most passives  involve some marking on the verb, but a  number of cases  have been mentioned in the literature that appear to be passives without special verbal
>   morphology.
>
> I claim that in general passive constructions without passive morphology do not exist.  On closer inspection it turns out that the alleged cases of
>   such passives should be analyzed differently.

He then goes on to list a few languages that following his approach do *not actually have* a passive, but only passive-like structures (or that have less passive constructions than previously thought) - among others English, Mandarin Chinese, Kinyarwanda, Acehnese and Palauan. (Edit: I might have misinterpreted this point a little: He does *not* propose that English has no passive at all, he only referred to one particular structure etc. - see the answer below! This does not make my question invalid, though.)

I'm not exactly sure whether I correctly grasp the extent of this approach.

**Are there any other languages that are commonly said to have a passive, but that do not, according to this definition?**

(E.g. the construction in Irish does not seem to count then, if I understand correctly - in the Doyle 2001 grammar, page 42, it says: "Modern Irish has a periphrastic passive, but no morphologically marked one."

> Excerpt from the grammar:
>
> "The periphrastic passive corresponds to  the three types of aspect mentioned above:
>
> - 1. Progressive passive - bí + Subject + PRT + VN
> - 2. Prospective passive - bí + Subject + le + VN
> - 3. Perfective passive - bí + Subject + verbal adjective (VA)
>
> Ta an  tae a   ól      ag  Maire. 
>   is the tea PRT drink-VN    at  Mary 
>   'The tea is being drunk by Mary.' "

Also: Using this approach, are there any languages where one would still consider the existence of a passive controversial?

Comment: Hmm, this reminds me of the arguments about whether English has a "future tense," since it is not morphologically marked.

Comment: Probably [Acehnese](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/acehnesequestions.pdf) (and for that matter, several versions of Malay) is an example of non-marked "passives". If they are passives. Which is impossible to determine, because Acehnese is not English.

Comment: @jlawler: I'm not sure if I understand. What makes English so important in deciding whether Acehnese has a passive?

Comment: Because English has one, and it works differently from what's called "passive" in Acehnese in some crucial ways (roughly, the passive verb still agrees with the original agent subject, instead of agreeing with the new passive subject). Is it the same phenomenon, or is it just a metaphor?

Answer (score 3):

Haspelmath's point is really one of terminology. He says that passives have to be morphologically marked and it is not enough for a construction to have a passive meaning with some possible corresponding change in syntax (word order). He does NOT actually say that English does not have a passive. Only that some constructions considered passive because of meaning/syntax such as 'destruction of the city by the enemy' are not actually passives. This is fairly sensible in the cases where additional constructions can claim the passive label - there are lots of constructions in English with passive meanings but no passive morphology ("they killed him" when *they* stands in for a generic de-emphasised agent) or in Slavic languages where things like reflexives are used in a similar way. Although, Haspelmath would accept the reflexive (or other) morphology as a possible way of morphologically marking the passive (a case of functional polysemy). But he does not make it clear how he classified languages where there are multiple morphological ways of expressing the passive but one canonical passive.

I'm not sure, that this is an all that interesting thing to ask. It would be somewhat interesting to see how many languages have had 'passive' identified simply under the theoretical assumption that all languages have a passive but it's ultimately a question of terminology. All those languages probably express some passive-like semantics through other means but those constructions do not have all the features of a passive but that is a question of how the term is defined - not one of what actually happens in the language which, as far as I can, tell is not really in dispute in most of these cases.

Comment: I guess I seriously misinterpreted the text then. Are you saying that even if a language has only a construction that is commonly referred to as a reflexive (but inherently can have passive meaning as well) it is sufficient to say that this language has a passive, according to Haspelmath? Also, would you say that he would count e.g. the construction in Irish as a passive?

Comment: How does "they killed him" have passive meaning??

Comment: The same way _He's too tired to do it_ "has passive meaning". The word "passive" is intrepreted like "passive aggression", though the grammatical passive construction has nothing to do with emotional or physical state. This is a subject on which [Geoff Pullum has waxed exceedingly wroth](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/passive_loathing.html).

Comment: @maj To be honest, I'm not sure exactly how Haspelmath would deal with the reflexive situation but his text seems to imply that this would include a passive because morphology is included. He says he's fine with a construction having multiple meanings.

Comment: @curiousdannii This perhaps wasn't a good example because the 'passive meaning' depends on context. Of course, 'X killed Y' is a prototype of an active construction. I was trying to focus on the generic impersonal 'they' or 'you' (as in, Imagine you kill someone.) which can be used to deemphasize the agent in the same way a passive does. Another example is things like ergative verbs in English as in 'The vase broke'.

Comment: @Dominik: Now that I think about it, *the reflexives specifically* might not even fit into H's passive definition, being "(i) the active subject corresponds either to a non-obligatory oblique phrase or to nothing, (ii) the active direct object (if any) corresponds to the subject of the passive, (iii) the construction  is somehow restricted vis-a-vis another unrestricted construction (the active), e.g. less frequent, functionally
specialized, not fully productive."

Comment: @maj I assume that in the languages he's talking about they will fit that definition but I don't know.

Comment: Okay. Sorry to repeat myself, but would the construction in Irish then count as passive? Does the *V*erbal *N*oun morpheme count as Verbal Morphology? It does not seem to be so.

Comment: @maj I don't know enough about Irish to be able to judge. I think he would probably exclude but it seems to me it reveals an inconsistency in his approach. Best ask him - he might respond to an email.

Comment: Thanks. But then again, Irish is only one of a set of languages that should make it into my database, if fit.

Comment: @DominikLukes "The vase broke" is not ergative! It has been called unaccusative though. I guess we're using these terms in completely different ways. Okay I get your point that a generic *they* could be thought of as deemphasizing the agent, but I think it is completely wrong to call that passive. A generic third person pronoun is just normal use for generic arguments.

Comment: They're being used in metaphorical ways. "Unergative" and "unaccusative" are terms that refer to phenomena that remind linguists of the way things work in other languages. Languages with ergative case systems have interesting syntax, and some English constructions get named that way. Just like the English 'subjunctive', which is so-called because it reminded early English grammarians of some uses the Latin subjunctive.

Comment: @curiousdannii You are right. 'The vase broke' is not ergative but these verbs have been called ergative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb).  

Also, thinking of generic 3rd person and other constructions as passive is not a point I was making. It is a position others have taken (most notably Givón) against which Haspelmath is reacting. I personally find these terminological discussions interesting only up to the point that they offer a new perspective on something. But it's not all that important what does or does not get called passive as long as it does not hide real variation.